# How to convert from a double without a fractional part to a hexaicosadecimal string (base-26)?

Tags: java, string, double

I am wondering  how do you convert from a double without a fractional part to a hexaicosadecimal string? What are some methods for converting and are there short cuts?

Comment: What language? Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: @Andy Sorry it's Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood it is a base 26 conversion to letters only, with a prefix "c". Not sure on the sign for a negative- number.

One "shortcut" would be to take the standard base 26 conversion.
Arguably doing the conversion oneself is just as easy, and would certainly give
a better note in homework.

```
static String hexaicosadecimal(double x) {
    long n = (long)x;
    String base26 = Long.toString(n, 26); // 0..9a.p
    return "c" + base26.codePoints()
        .map(cp -> '0' <= cp && cp <= '9' ? 'A' + (cp - '0')
                        : 'a' <= cp && cp < 'a' + 16 ? 'A' + 10 + (cp - 'a')
                        : cp) // '-'
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: `mapToInt` -> `map`?

Comment: @saka1029 thanks, corrected.