# How to convert from a double with or without a fractional part to a hexaicosadecimal string (Base-26)?

Tags: java, string, double

What is the way to convert from a double with or without a fractional part to a hexaicosadecimal string? What are some tips or possible shortcuts?

Comment: See [How to convert from a double without a fractional part to a hexaicosadecimal string (base-26)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220487/how-to-convert-from-a-double-without-a-fractional-part-to-a-hexaicosadecimal-str/69221158?noredirect=1#comment122359792_69221158)

Comment: 1) Please don't play silly games with opening multiple accounts.  It is not strictly against the rules, but a lot of things that people (try to) use multiple accounts for definitely ARE against the rules.   2)  Don't repost a questions that you have already asked.  People are not stupid.  They remember when they've seen a question before ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For any base `B`, multiply the factional decimal number part by `B`.
- If the number is >= 1, assign to an int and convert to 0-F as appropriate.
- save only the previous fraction and continue from the beginning.

Here is an example for binary.

```
double d = .2342;
System.out.print(".");
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    d = 2*d;
    int bit = (int)d;
    System.out.print(bit);
    d = d-bit;
}
System.out.println();
```

Prints the following for .2342 with 20 bits of accuracy

```
.00111011111101001000
```

Note that since floating point products of fractions can degrade, care must be taken for long strings. And unless the fraction is a power of.5, it will be repeating.